# Using NetBeans to debug PHP?

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, ubuntu, xdebug

**UPDATE 1:**

I have made a change in:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

looks like this:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

phpinfo looks like this:

```
debug           
xdebug support      enabled 
Version     2.0.5   
Supported protocols     Revision    
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol     $Revision: 1.125.2.6 $  
GDB - GNU Debugger protocol     $Revision: 1.87 $   
PHP3 - PHP 3 Debugger protocol      $Revision: 1.22 $   
Directive   Local Value     Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off     Off
xdebug.collect_includes On      On
xdebug.collect_params   0       0
xdebug.collect_return   Off     Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off     Off
xdebug.default_enable   On      On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value        no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value        no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value        no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value        no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value        no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value        no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value        no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value        no value
xdebug.dump_globals On      On
xdebug.dump_once    On      On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off     Off
xdebug.extended_info    On      On
xdebug.idekey   no value        no value
xdebug.manual_url   http://www.php.net      http://www.php.net
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100     100
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off     Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off     Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off     Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off     Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp        /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p       cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off     Off
xdebug.remote_enable    On      On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp        dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost       localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value        no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req     req
xdebug.remote_port  9000        9000
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off     Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off     Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off     Off
xdebug.trace_format 0       0
xdebug.trace_options    0       0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp        /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c        trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128     128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512     512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3       3
```

I have checked netbeans `tools > options > php` settings and they are as they have been described in the first answer below.  I then select an if statement, click `ctrl+f8` an add a line break, and I am not sure what to do next, as most of the `debug` and `run` options in netbeans are disabled.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have tried following many guides, but I can't seem to get php debugging in netbeans to work

I have installed lamp stack, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans php plugin, and added the following to `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini`:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

If I then restart apache2 and load netbeans and open a php page and add a breakpoint, all the debug and run options are disabled in netbeans...

What am I doing wrong?

I am using ubuntu 10.04, and everything is installed via the standard ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xdebug settings seem fine, although you might need to add another line

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

And you probably need to check/change a few settings in Netbeans. Go to Tools - Options - PHP - General and verify that the debugger port is set to 9000 (as is your xdebug port) and the session id is set to `netbeans-xdebug`

You can verify that xdebug is running when you go to a page that calls `phpinfo()` and check for `xdebug` in the output.

Comment: Seems to be working for only for php projects, not if i open a stand along php file.