# How we debug cakephp using Netbeans?

Tags: cakephp, netbeans

I am a beginner of cakephp. I am using netbeans IDE. Is there any netbeans plugin for debugging cakephp script ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693074/how-to-debug-php-with-netbeans-and-xdebug (Windows) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835454/using-netbeans-to-debug-php (Linux)

Comment: Debugging CakePHP has nothing to do with your IDE or text editor.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use XDebug. Here is a link on how to set up XDebug with NetBeans http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Answer (score 1):

You can always put

```
debug($variable);
die; //if you want to stop the program
```

and you will get the value of the variable. It's like printf(); for C if you are not using debugger. :D

Comment: gark, yes you can, and that's sometimes the easiest thing, but much nicer to use the proper debugger: xdebug.

Comment: I agree that is nicer but, most of my development time, I just need to print a variable. Nothing else... So the "printf", ups, "debug" is a great solution. ^^

Comment: Agreed, but in Stackoverflow answers you should always at least mention the right way as well as the quick way ;)