# How to step into a php function to see how it works in the Netbeans IDE?

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have a code like this:

```
<?php
function list_cmp($a, $b) {
    global $order;

    foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
        if ($a == $value) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ($b == $value) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

$order[0] = 1;
$order[1] = 3;
$order[2] = 4;
$order[3] = 2;

$array[0] = 2;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 4;
$array[4] = 2;
$array[5] = 1;
$array[6] = 2;

usort($array, "list_cmp");
```

I've been trying to debug this piece of code in Netbeans, but I cant get it to work (as an example, the debugger buttons or menu functions are not accessible, I am not sure why). What are the exact steps (and prerequisites) of getting this to work? I want to see the indyvidual steps of usort() with the list_cmp().

Comment: same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274723/how-the-usort-sorting-algorithm-works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using NetBeans to debug PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835454/using-netbeans-to-debug-php)